# “The server was not found or was not accessible” Error for SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, iis

Error message is like this:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 51 - An instance name was not specified while connecting to a Local Database Runtime. Specify an instance name in the format (localdb)\instance_name.)

And my scenario: IIS and SQL Server 2008 are on the same test workstation, whose firewall is not enabled at all. I don't see any SQL Server log so I can't find any other useful information than the error message above.

I installed SQL Server as default instance (`MSSQLSERVER`)

My connection string is like this (I am using SQL Server account for authentication):

```
Server=(localdb); Database=MY_DB_NAME; User ID=MY_USER_ID; Password=MY_PASSWORD
```

I already verified this user has access to the target database (as owner)

I have gone through some articles on how to track down this problem: I set "allow remote connection" even though IIS and SQL Server are on the same machine. I don't need to set-up firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a standard, unnamed instance, you should use `.` or `(local)` (but **not** `(localdb)` !) as your server name

Try to use this connection string:

```
Server=(local); Database=MY_DB_NAME; User ID=MY_USER_ID; Password=MY_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I swear to god I tried both . or (local) at some point which didn't work. But I guess that was when something else was wrong because now when I tried (local), or my local IP address, they are both working. Thank you!